# CasperJS: login Form not found

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have tried capturing a form but it says "form not found".

I did the below

```
this.test.assertExists('//*[@id="#loginForm"]', 'form is found');

this.fill('', {
    login:"**********",
    password:"**********",

}, true);
```

my html code is below

```
<form id="#loginForm" class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
```

I tried also "form##loginForm", but I'm always seeing "form not found".

Comment: Also tried form[action="/login"]

Comment: <form id="#loginForm" class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">

Comment: hi , as the answer is helping me but i am still not able to click the element because the tool is just checking the html content ,                                      The login form opens up after a ajax call and that is the reason none of my web elements are seen. can u help me what should i do to check the ajax call every time the page load to proceed further.

Comment: please help me on this i am a beginner and struck. can i talk to u in person to understand more on this

Answer (score 0):

`'//*[@id="#loginForm"]'` is an XPath expression. Nearly all CasperJS functions support XPath expressions, but you need to use a helper function to distinguish between XPath expressions and CSS selectors:

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
...
this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@id="#loginForm"]'), 'form is found (xpath)');
this.test.assertExists('[id="#loginForm"]', 'form is found (css)');
```

Other issues might be:

- The form is inside of a frame, so you need to switch into the frame with [`casper.withFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe).
- There may be a problem with the underlying browser. You could register to different events in order to get a glimpse of what might be going wrong. You can try the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)).
- You also should take a screenshot (`casper.capture()`) frequently to see if you're on the correct page or if the page is fully loaded. If it is not, then you need to investigate why that might be and which previous step failed. Maybe you only need to wait an additional time.

---

In case the form is loaded asynchronously you need to wait for it to appear like this:

```
var formSelector = x('//*[@id="#loginForm"]');
casper.waitForSelector(formSelector, function _then(){
    this.fill(formSelector, {
        login: "**********",
        password: "**********",
    }, true);
}, function _onTimeout(){
    this.test.fail("Login form loaded");
} /* , 5000 */); // timeout is 5 seconds by default
```